# Stale elements in list even after updating

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium to automate a simple click-and-drag matching game.

In the game, there are 12 tiles, (six pairs of matching tiles). The tiles on the website are listed in order, so I'm just storing all the tiles in a list, and then iterating through the list, clicking and dragging every 2 tiles in order to match every element. Both tiles get deleted in the game after they touch.

However, when I run the loop, it does nothing but throw stale element exceptions.

Here's the code:

```
match_tiles=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"MatchModeQuestionScatterTile")

for i in range(0,12,2):
    try:
        print("target: "+match_tiles[i].get_attribute("textContent"))
        print("destination: "+match_tiles[i+1].get_attribute("textContent"))
        actions.click_and_hold(match_tiles[i])
        time.sleep(1)
        actions.move_to_element(match_tiles[i+1])
        time.sleep(1)
        actions.release().perform()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

And here's the output:

```
target: Q
destination: q
target: C
destination: c
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
```

For example, if `match_tiles` contains WebElements whose `textContent`s are

`[o,O,r,R,b,B,m,M,h,H,l,L]`

```
target: o
destination: O
target: r
destination: R
target: b
destination: B
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

target: m
destination: M
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

target: h
destination: H
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

target: l
destination: L
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
```

The first match works, but after that the elements become stale. I've tried updating match_tiles after each loop to no avail. I've added some delays in hopes of letting the page load first but it doesn't seem to work either.

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As it is getting deleted after moving, the element will not be available after the move. the following code may work.

```
match_tiles=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"MatchModeQuestionScatterTile")

for i in range(6):
    try:
        print("target: "+match_tiles[0].get_attribute("textContent"))
        print("destination: "+match_tiles[1].get_attribute("textContent"))
        actions.click_and_hold(match_tiles[0])
        time.sleep(1)
        actions.move_to_element(match_tiles[1])
        time.sleep(1)
        actions.release().perform()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    match_tiles=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"MatchModeQuestionScatterTile")
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried the above code but the same error occurred-- ```match_tiles``` stay the same at the end of the loop even after the refresh, even though the first two elements have degraded.

Comment: What I mean is that when I execute that last line and then print the elements of ```match_tiles```, the degraded elements' names are still printed.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe I got the root cause
If there are 12 tiles then according to the below statement

```
match_tiles=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"MatchModeQuestionScatterTile")
```

I believe this return list of `12 elements`
but the problem is when the first time you drag and drop your first matching tile both tiles get disappeared now you have `10 tiles left` and you are still iterating the `list of 12 elements` which does not exist and because of that you are getting a `stale element exception` because you are trying to iterate on such elements which even not exist in UI.

To overcome this issue what you need to do is try to find a list of elements every time inside your loop and create logic according to that.